# Creating multiple UIViews from button pressed Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiview

I have a UIView called brokeView, It is draggable and rotational. I am trying to allow the user to populate the same exact view from clicking a button allowing an endless amount of the same UIView to populate. Is this possible to do in swift using the storyboard? 
- Do I have to create all the views in storyboard or could I populate them through code using an array or loop?

```
@IBOutlet weak var brokeView: UIView!

  @IBAction func showBrokenAnnotation(sender: AnyObject) {
        brokeView.hidden = false
        for i in 1...10 {
            print(i)
            let newView = UIView(frame: brokeView.bounds)
            brokeView.addSubview(newView)
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done through code. Here is some pseudo code.

Updated from our conversation below - this makes it the same size as your "brokenView" and then you can set the x/y however you want.

```
 let newView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: mainView.frame.width, height: mainView.frame.height))

 self.view.addSubview(newView)
```

Comment: I have tried this, the view won't appear. Thanks for trying!

Comment: That will work assuming everything else is setup correctly. Change the color of the new views as they are added to debug.

Comment: Posted some code, the View was created from storyboard, I am trying to allow the user to create more of the same view if they need it, whether it be 1 or 2 or 3 etc...

Comment: Just fixed it meant to write brokeView, tornView is another view the same as brokeView just different properties

Comment: Add a background color to the "newView" to see if it is actually showing up. You could also use Xcode's view debugger.

Comment: To use the view debugger just hit the button in this image while your app is running: http://imgur.com/gpLrCsp

Comment: it looks like the views loaded, but they are appearing as the same exact view, not new ones

Comment: Oh well you can add it to whatever view you want. I thought you wanted it inside the brokenView. See my edit.

Comment: could you show an example of it using the CGRect? Also could i only  add one at a time as well ?

Comment: How could I make the user in control of how many he or she wants to create? Thank you so much for all your help already!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115324/discussion-between-richmond-watkins-and-frank-boccia).